# Is the information given in this rings exercise necessary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The exercise is the following:

> Let $\theta: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism and let $A \subseteq R$ and $B \subseteq S$ be ideals. If $\theta(A) \subseteq B$, show that $\theta$ induces a unique ring homomorphism $\bar \theta: R/A \to S/B$ such that $\bar \theta \varphi = \varphi' \theta$ (where $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ are the coset maps of $R \to R/A$ and $B \to S/B$, respectively).

The action of $\bar\theta$ is completely determined, so it is unique (right?):
$$
\bar\theta(r+A) = \bar \theta\varphi(r) = \varphi'\theta(r) = \theta(r) + B.
$$

And we have
$$
\bar\theta[(r+A)(s+A)] = \bar\theta(rs+A) = \theta(rs) + B = \theta(r) \theta(s) + B = (\theta(r)+B)(\theta(s)+B) = \bar\theta(r+A) \bar\theta(s+A).
$$

Similarly, $\bar\theta[(r+A)+(s+A)] = \bar\theta[(r+A)] + \bar\theta[(s+A)]$ and $\bar\theta(0+A) = 0 + B$, so $\bar\theta$ is a homomorphism, completing the exercise. Except, probably not. What am I supposed to do with the fact that $\theta(A) \subseteq B$?

Comment: Did you prove the function is well-defined? If $r+A =r'+A$, is  $\theta(r)+B$ necessarily equal to $\theta(r')+B$? If not, you don't even have a function, let alone a homomorphism...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh man i forgot the most important part lol